# How to get correct date format in ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, weather-api

I have an function to get forecast weather ajax to load this into div but the date in `json` have a datetime `format type: "dt":1452254400`

I need format: `'Y-m-d'` but in ajax I can't use the `gmdate()` php function to get this.

I'm trying get this with

```
  $.ajax({
    url: urlforecast,
    dataType:"JSON",
    success:function(data){
       var str = (""+data['list'][0]['dt']);

       var num = parseInt(str.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ""));
       var date = new Date(num);
       alert(date);
```

But he format is: `Sat Jan 17 1970 20:29:56 GMT+0100` and I dislike this.

How can I get the format like `gmdate()` into `ajax` function?

Comment: You're converting a number to string (`""+data['list'][0]['dt']`) only to parse it as a number again (`parseInt()`). Why?

Answer (score 0):

You have seconds since epoch, javascript uses milliseconds, so you have to multiply by a thousand

```
$.ajax({
    url      : urlforecast,
    dataType : "JSON",
    success  : function(data){
        var num  = (+data['list'][0]['dt']) * 1000;
        var date = new Date(num);
    }
});
```

To get `Y-m-d` you'd do

```
var date = new Date(num);
var ymd  = date.getFullYear() + '-' + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + date.getDate();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try multiplying `num` by `1000` , using `.toJSON()`, `String.prototype.slice()`

```js
var num = 1452254400;
var ymd = new Date(num * 1000).toJSON().slice(0, 10);
console.log(ymd)
```